# I'm looking for music Transposition and tablature software applications

Tags: sheet-music

Is there any free, open source software to use in music transposition and tabbing? I'm on latest Windows. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, @TopCat. Looking for software/equipment suggestions is considered offtopic for this website. Consider visiting https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi TopCat. Welcome to Music Practice & Theory. We don't make software recommendations, but if you search around the site for "transcription" and "software", for example, you may find helpful references to different packages.